# Nested function calls in CMake (use one's result as another's argument)

Tags: function, cmake

Test CMakeLists.txt:

```
function(foo param)
    return("hello")
endfunction()

message(foo("oops"))
```

When "cmake ." is run with the above file, it prints "foo(oops)".  I expected it to print "hello".

How can I make one function receive the result of another in CMake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake functions don't "return values" in the way the code example you gave thinks they do.  In general, if a CMake builtin or function wants to return a value, it needs to take the name of a variable to store the result in:

```
function(foo param ret)
    set(${ret} "hello ${param}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

Then, you need to construct the control flow in the caller yourself:

```
foo("world" hello_world)
message(STATUS "foo returned: ${hello_world}")
foo(${hello_world} hello2)
message(STATUS "foo second call returned: ${hello2}")
```

Comment: What does "return(x)" do in CMake?  Just ignores x?  It looks that way, though the docs don't say this.  Also, are you surprised that not only does the function `foo()` not return a value, it isn't even called in my example!

Comment: The documentation gives the syntax as just `return()` so `return(x)` would be undefined behavior, I guess.  I'm also not at all surprised foo is never being called in the example - that would be like putting `echo ls` in a shell script where you shouldn't be surprised `ls` never gets run.